# What does "it" refer to in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I moved sideways toward center stage. Hours earlier, I wasn't sure I'd have the strength to do what I was about to do, but now I felt emboldened and potent. I dropped to the floor and began doing pushups.
In the audience's laughter and surprised applause, **It** was almost as if I could hear everyone collectively exhaling their anxiety. **It** wasn't just some dying man. **it** was just me. I could begin.

in "The LAST LECTURE" p40

What does it refer to in the bolded parts? In Korean, I think it would be a correct sentence without "it was". (I am Korean.)

Comment: Presumably the book by Pausch and Zaslow? The first 'it' is a [dummy subject](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects) referring to the situation.

Comment: This book is written by "Randy Pausch with Jeffrey Zaslow"(says on the cover)

Comment: But people reading your question can't see the cover! You need to specify the name(s) of the author(s) in your question.

Comment: I will do that from next time, and the answer to the question was understood, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It" can be used as a '*dummy subject*' - usually the situation at hand, or something being experienced. For example, "*it is raining*". The first instance of 'it' is exactly that - the situation being experienced by the first person as they walk onto the stage. They experience seeing the audience for the first time and the reaction to them being on stage, and *that* is what they say is "*almost as if I could hear everyone collectively exhaling their anxiety*".

The second two uses are the first person referring to themselves. We do not use 'it' as a pronoun for a person, but we can use it to add emphasis - for example, "***it's** me!*" is a way of drawing attention to yourself or announcing yourself as the answer to a question such as "*who is **it?***". This is called a *cleft sentence*. The first person has just spoken of the audience's *relief* ('exhaling', or letting go of their anxiety). Evidently, they thought that they might be presented with a "dying man" but *it* wasn't - *it* was the first person.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! your answer is very helpful!